# Is it possible to add your own annotations or pause at a custom time when embedding a YouTube video?

Tags: php, mysql, youtube

So I'm currently using php to randomly choose a YouTube video from a MySql database into an iframe.

I'm trying to see if I can get the video to pause at a custom time (the time is easy enough to get from the database), or bring up an annotation and pause.

I've looked at various solutions, but none seem to be based on varying times for random videos. Any ideas?

Comment: you would need to make a container that you control that inturn tells the youtube video what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I simply set an end point using `&end=xx` at the end of the url, and am using javascript to remove it to let people play beyond that point

```
var src=document.getElementById("video").getAttribute("src")
var subsrc=src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf("&"));
```

Simple enough